# Force MigLayout shrink like GridBagLayout for hidden Objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, miglayout

I am trying to replace `GridBagLayout` with `MigLayout`. The problem is that if i call `obj.setVisible(false)` for some object in `GridBaglayout`, the layout shrinks. But in `MigLayout` it just remains hidden. Do you know some way to make `MigLayout` acting like `GridBagLayout`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the "hidemode" property on the MigLayout Cheat Sheet over here:

http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html

You probably want `new MigLayout("hidemode 3")`