# How do I shrink a Miglayout row height to zero when I hide components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I have a simple Miglayout dialog with rows consisting of JLabels and JTextFields.  The visiblility of a number of the components is set depending on the circumstances.  However, when they are hidden the row height remains the same leaving a blank area.

I have set the min row height to 0px and also have other rows set to 'grow', but this doesn't seem to help.  Surely, if a row can be 0px high and its contents are hidden, then it should shrink shouldn't it?  Obviously I'm missing something!

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the hidemode of the layout to prevent invisible components from affecting the layout.

From http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html :

> Sets the default hide mode for the layout. This hide mode can be overridden by the component constraint. The hide mode specified how the layout manager should handle a component that isn't visible. The modes are:
>   0 - Default. Means that invisible components will be handled exactly as if they were visible.
>   1 - The size of an invisible component will be set to 0, 0.
>   2 - The size of an invisible component will be set to 0, 0 and the gaps will also be set to 0 around it.
>   3 - Invisible components will not participate in the layout at all and it will for instance not take up a grid cell.

Answer (score 3):

Why is it that I can only find answers to my problems *after* I post queries online?  Seems I overlooked the following QA: [Force MigLayout shrink like GridBagLayout for hidden Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190358/force-miglayout-shrink-like-gridbaglayout-for-hidden-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call `panel.revalidate()` to layout the components after their visibility changes.